# Control all runned applications from one notifyIcon menu

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

I have an application that runs 8-10 times at the same time. When this application runned for the first time, I created a `notifyIcon1` in the system tray, and not in the next runs. I also added a menu to this `notifyIcon1`. However, the menu is active only the first runned application. What should I do to control all opened applications from this menu?
The application name is `WindowsFormsApp1.exe` and the codes are as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TrayMenuContext();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var count = Process.GetProcessesByName("WindowsFormsApp1").Length;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = count == 1;
        }
        private void TrayMenuContext()
        {
            notifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
            notifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Close all apps...", null, notifyIcon1_Close_Click);
            notifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Minimize all apps...", null, notifyIcon1_Minimize_Click);
            notifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Show all apps...", null, notifyIcon1_Show_Click);
        }
        void notifyIcon1_Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        void notifyIcon1_Minimize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        void notifyIcon1_Show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably start by looping through all the processes looking for your running applications.

Comment: @LarsTech - I tried ´Process.GetProcessesByName("WindowsFormsApp1")´ but it not contain `Form` so for example `WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;` not work.

Comment: This is not the answer to my question. Because 'WindowsFormsApp1' applications we open will have so much 'ProcessById'. And every time the application is opened, it will get a different `ProcessById.

Comment: Right.  So loop through them and find the reference to the form handle.